# Link 32bits library on 64bit system and program

Tags: gcc, linker, x86-64, 32bit-64bit, ld

I have a shared objects file libfoo.so, which I believe is 32bits:

```
libfoo.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=....
```

I'm developing on 64bits Linux, can I just link to the library, or do I have to use `-m32` switch, in which case, all my code will be built into 32 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All code has to be the same bitness for it to link.  Get a 64-bit version of the library if you can, otherwise you're stuck with `-m32` to make a crusty old 32-bit executable.